Simulating ADC Effects on DSP Algorithm with Fixed-Point Representation
Let's say i expect two narrowband signals, signal-A is -1dBFS and signal-B is approx -40dBc. I have an adc with 13-bits ENOB, 65 MSPS, SINAD 81dBFS and output voltage range -1.8V to 1.8V. Now before i move onto the hardware implementation (FPGA) of my dsp algorithm, i'd like to simulate the algorithm with signal resolution of 13-bits fixed point in the range -1.8 to 1.8.
How should i approach this? 
How can i find my Q value for fixed point representation? 
How to convert the signal data to 13-bits ranging from -1.8 to 1.8? (the simulation i have done uses float64)
I am doing this to know what to expect from the output of the hardware and how quantization noise affect the algorithm.

For such a simulation integer values would be just fine (or you can use any other Q value you want, it won't affect the simulation as long as the waveform is scaled to match that representation).
To determine the effect of the ADC you need to consider the following items assuming other factors in the analog to digital process such as anti-alias filtering have already been considered:

The ENOB (effective number of bits) which is given on the data sheet at an assumed test condition (back-off from full scale, sampling rate and input frequency of a single tone used for that test). Good datasheets will expand on this with charts so that you have an idea of how the ENOB is affected as you vary those conditions.

Maximum possible spurious conditions due to other ADC non-linearities which is also give on the datasheet as the Spurious free dynamic range.

The distribution of your waveform in comparison to a sine wave that is used to determine ENOB. This will allow you to consider additional clipping noise and what back-off from full scale would be appropriate for your design (as typically set by an AGC (Automatic Gain Control) adjustment of the signal at the ADC input, assuming the input signal strength is varying.  Ideally testing and ADC parameters are determined for a specific waveform of interest but short of that such a simulation described here can provide initial guidance prior to having first hardware.


That said, to set up such a simulation simply, it can be assumed to a first order approximation that the total noise power due to quantization noise is equivalent to that of a perfect ADC with the same number of bits as ENOB (not the actual bits in the converter). For that use, convert your signal to a quantized signal by using a back-off parameter for the rms value of your waveform and scaling to the integer values representing the full scale range of the ADC.
As an example, let's assume your ENOB is 11.5 bits with a sine wave backed off -1 dB from full-scale (these are reasonable for a 13 bit converter), and the peak input voltage of a sine wave at the threshold of actual clipping for the ADC as powered/configured is +/-1.8V (full-scale):
This means the peak level of the sine wave adjusted for the 1 dB backoff, where we optimize the dynamic range due to quantization noise (which is how ENOB is determined) would be given as follows:
$$V_{p} = 1.8 \times 10^{-1/20} \approx 1.43 \text{ 
   } V$$
(The indication on the datasheet that ENOB was determined with a 1 dB backoff, in my example, means that if we were to increase the sine wave amplitude further, the overall SNR would degrade, meaning ENOB would be lower, due to non-linearities at the ADC input).
Thus the full scale range of the equivalent perfect 11.5 bit ADC is $\pm 1.43$ V ($2.86 V_{pp}$).
Note too for purpose of establishing the signal to noise ratio for the ADC (which is also how ENOB is determined), the "signal" level for SNR is the rms of the sine wave tone used for this test, or $(1/\sqrt{2})V_p = \sigma_{tone} \approx 1.13 \text{   } V_{rms}$
From this we can map any waveform $x(t)$ in units of volts to quantized values $x[n]$ using the 11.5 bits as follows. I will use units of counts to represent integer ADC values, so this is simply converting volts to counts. We have 1.43 volts mapped to a range of $2^{11.5-1}$ total counts as a signed integer result:
$$x[n] = \lfloor (x(nT) 2^{11.5-1}/1.43\rfloor \text{ counts}$$
The $\lfloor \text{ } \rfloor$ represent truncation. Rounding could also be used which only effects the DC offset (to half a quantization level).  $x(nT)$ represents the discrete values at the sampling period $T$, prior to being quantized in amplitude.
Further to capture the effects of clipping, a subsequent process step in the simulation is also needed to convert any samples that exceed the ADC full scale maximum and minimum values to be those maximum or minimum values: $$\text{if } x[n] < -2^{11.5-1}, x[n] = -2^{11.5-1}$$
$$\text{ if } x[n] > 2^{11.5-1}-1, x[n] = 2^{11.5-1} -1$$
The one bit difference between full scale positive and negative will be of no consequence so could just as easily just use $\pm2^{10.5}$ as the test threshold if desired.
The rms level of $x[n]$ would typically be significantly lower than that of the sine wave that determined ENOB. The ENOB establishes a reference point for the ADC noise floor for any input waveform based on the value where a sine wave would start to clip, given the ENOB and the relationship between ENOB and SNR:
$$SNR = 6.02 \times ENOB + 1.76 \text{ dB}$$
An important point is as we lower the level of the sine wave, the power due to quantization noise does not change! But also if we use any other waveform besides a sine-wave, we may vary likely introduce clipping which means the above is used to set the full-scale of the ADC for the simulation, but not the level of the signal. This is important!
The optimum level of the signal is affected by the distribution of the waveform itself. A sine wave has a peak to average ratio of 3 dB, which is the peak of the sine wave vs it's rms level (the square of which is its average power). Other waveforms can easily have peak to average ratios in excess of 10 dB, which would result in significant clipping if the input of the waveform was set to be the same power level (same rms level) as the sine wave at the full-scale condition. For this reason, the actual waveform needs to be backed off from full scale to avoid clipping.   With such a simulation being set-up, it would be simple to just have a gain parameter and evaluate an SNR metric by evaluating the rms error between $x(nT)$ and $x[n]$ as the rms level of the waveform is varied.
The chart I show below shows the optimum waveform back-off based on number of bits (ENOB) and assuming here a Gaussian distributed waveform (which sets the curve for the clipping noise contribution). "Full Scale Sine Wave" on the chart represents the $\sigma_{tone} =1.13 V_{rms}$ level determined earlier, as an rms level -3 dB below the peak level. For and ENOB of 11.5 bits, we see from this chart that we would minimize the total ADC noise with a signal level at -13 dB below 0 dB, or -10 dB below the full-scale sine (so 10 dB back-off is optimum assuming a Gaussian distributed waveform).

Like what you see? This plot and similar explanations are part of my DSP courses where I try to bring intuition together with the math involved for a deeper and more creative understanding of signal processing concepts. I go into extended detail of optimizing ADC sampling for software radio in my "DSP for Software Radio" course starting again in August 2024! You can find the latest course listings at https://dsprelated.com/courses and https://ieeeboston.org/courses/  !

I am not sure i understand what you mean by using integers (counts) for simulation. If thats the case why would anyone bother with floating and fixed point representation?. Is 11.5bits the real world expected value when the signal is down by 1dB from full scale?, I thought the signal have to be 9dB down to lose 1.5bits from 13bits ENOB. I think $V_p$ should be 1.604V. Are the conditions for clipping correct?. Shoudn't it be $\textbf{if}\ x[n] < -2^{10.5}, x[n] = -2^{10.5}$

Integers is just a simple way of representing fixed point, and would be the "fast path" to do what you want here. When I implement fixed point filters and other fixed point designs I would typically use a Q(m,n) notation which just makes my life easier but doesnn't change the binary values ultimately used.

The -1dB is the analog rms level of a full scale sine wave relative to that level where it would actually start clipping consistent with the example I gave. As you decrease the sine wave (or any waveform) at the ADC input, SNR degrades since the quantization noise level does not change (so you push the signal into the noise). However as you get close to full scale (see the datasheet for specifics, it could be -1.5 dB etc depending on the device) the SNR will start to degrade again due to non-linearities that occur. And yes you're correct, I'll fix that clipping error!

Also if you have two narrow band signals each -dBFS, then you will certainly be clipping even if those signals were tones. Not sure if that is what you want but if they were tones they should be < -3 dBFS to ensure no clipping and if there is any modulation likely lower than that. You'll see that easily enough in your sim as long as you have a knob to adjust the overall level relative to full scale of the ADC. Good luck with your sim and hope this all was helpful to you!

Is it like how you want to interpret the binary value as?, I can see it as counts from $-2^{10.5}$ to $2^{10.5}-1$ or as a fixed point with Q(2, 9.5) from -1.8 to 1.8 but regardless of how i choose to interpret it, the underlying binary does not change, am i right?

The reason for -1dBFS is because i didn't know any better. I thought adc would start clipping on or after 1.8V not before that, so -1dbFS looked like a good safe limit. The signal magnitudes i have mentioned are relative, the difference between the two signals is about 40dB give or take, i think i can push it down to <-3dBFS, its fine as long as i have about 18dB room between the weakest signal and the noise floor+spurs. All of this is based on my limited understanding, i will have to some hardware simulation to make sure everything is right.

Regarding the plot, I couldn't find a similar one in the ad9650 datasheet. And according to the plot, the signal have to be around -13dBFS to get the maximum SQNR for a 12-bit adc?, isn't -13dBFS a little too much?.

Yes I agree re Q(m,n). My plot (and described in the text) is for a Gaussian distributed signal, which has peaks much higher than the rms level and for that reason the rms level needs to be backed off much more to avoid clipping. -3 dB on tat chart is the rms level where a sine wave would clip - and that is what is referred to as "Full Scale" for an ADC. So -1dBFS on my chart is -4 dB, and a 12 bit adc would be -10 dBFS (assuming Gaussian distributed).  You need to look at your own peak to rms level ratio and trade clipping noise with quantization noise which is what my post here describes.

In my simulation, the values fluctuates between 660 to -550 float32. Assuming the signal will be within the mentioned range, how can i convert it into integers?. My approach is, I divide by 110, to get the range to 6 to -5, subtract the mean and i get 5.5 to -5.5, 4.901 to -4.901 to account for -1dBFS. Now to get the counts $x[n] =  \lfloor x(nT)2^{10.5}/4.901 \rfloor$. Is this right?, if not can you give me an example on how to do it?

Please post as a new question with the specifics as the system will flag us if we have ongoing discussion in the comments. Thanks
